# How do I use material-ui in electron

Tags: electron, material-ui

My code always gave me an error in the electron console, however the same code did not give me an  error in a web browser:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory ,hashHistory} from 'react-router'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import { RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <RaisedButton className="submit" label='xxxxxxx' labelColor="#fff" backgroundColor="#32a62e"></RaisedButton>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

injectTapEventPlugin();

let rootElement = document.getElementById('containers');
render(
  <App/>,
  rootElement
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();
```

to the top level of your javascript files as explained in [this](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation) page of the documentation . It's because there is a dependencey on this module for `onTouchTap` to work So move it up before the class definition or to the top js file you have.

Comment: The code web broser is good and Electron not good  and have injectTapEventPlugin()